# Using React Native Webview with React Native 0.37

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

I'm trying to install [RN Webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/) as Apple is going to depreciate the existing WebView. I'm having some issues with the installation.

Note: Our project is on RN 0.37 and upgrading cannot be done immediately.

After installing and linking the library, when running we get several import issues.

`#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>` -> In `RNCWebViewManager.h`

> 'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found

These were resolved by how we import the files.

`#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>` -> `#import "RCTViewManager.h"`

This was done for all imports that was imported from React.

After that, we're getting the following errors.

> In file included from
>   /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:8: /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.h:23:29:
>   warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull,
>   _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness] @property (nonatomic, weak) id scriptDelegate;
>                               ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.h:23:54:
>   note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null @property
>   (nonatomic, weak) id scriptDelegate;
>                                                        ^
>                                                          _Nullable /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.h:23:54:
>   note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null @property
>   (nonatomic, weak) id scriptDelegate;
>                                                        ^
>                                                          _Nonnull /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.h:24:4:
>   warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull,
>   _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
>   - (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id)scriptDelegate;
>   ^
>   /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.h:24:4:
>   note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
>   - (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id)scriptDelegate;
>   ^
>                   _Nullable  /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.h:24:4:
>   note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
>   - (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id)scriptDelegate;
>   ^
>                   _Nonnull  /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.h:24:35:
>   warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull,
>   _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
>   - (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id)scriptDelegate;
>                                     ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.h:24:60:
>   note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
>   - (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id)scriptDelegate;
>                                                              ^
>                                                               _Nullable /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.h:24:60:
>   note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
>   - (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id)scriptDelegate;
>                                                              ^
>                                                               _Nonnull /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:108:3:
>   warning: 'UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior' is only
>   available on iOS 11.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
>   UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior
>   _savedContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior;   ^ In module 'UIKit' imported from ../../react-native/React/Views/RCTView.h:12:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIScrollView.h:35:28:
>   note: 'UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior' has been marked as
>   being introduced in iOS 11.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS
>   8.0.0 typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior) {
>                              ^ In file included from /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:8: /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.h:27:12:
>   note: annotate 'RNCWebView' with an availability attribute to silence
>   this warning @interface RNCWebView : RCTView
>              ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:394:44:
>   warning: 'UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior' is only
>   available on iOS 11.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
>   - (void)setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:(UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior)behavior
>                                              ^ In module 'UIKit' imported from ../../react-native/React/Views/RCTView.h:12:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIScrollView.h:35:28:
>   note: 'UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior' has been marked as
>   being introduced in iOS 11.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS
>   8.0.0 typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior) {
>                              ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:394:1:
>   note: annotate 'setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:' with an
>   availability attribute to silence this warning
>   - (void)setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:(UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior)behavior
>   ^
>   /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:129:28:
>   error: implicit declaration of function 'RCTSharedApplication' is
>   invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>       _savedStatusBarStyle = RCTSharedApplication().statusBarStyle;
>                              ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:129:50:
>   error: member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union
>       _savedStatusBarStyle = RCTSharedApplication().statusBarStyle;
>                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:130:51:
>   error: member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union
>       _savedStatusBarHidden = RCTSharedApplication().statusBarHidden;
>                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:138:44:
>   warning: 'UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever' is only available
>   on iOS 11.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
>       _savedContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
>                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In module 'UIKit' imported
>   from ../../react-native/React/Views/RCTView.h:12:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIScrollView.h:35:28:
>   note: 'UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior' has been marked as
>   being introduced in iOS 11.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS
>   8.0.0 typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior) {
>                              ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:138:44:
>   note: enclose 'UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever' in an
>   @available check to silence this warning
>       _savedContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
>                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:270:27:
>   warning: 'setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:' is only available on iOS
>   11.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
>         _webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = _savedContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior;
>                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In module 'UIKit' imported from ../../react-native/React/Views/RCTView.h:12:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIScrollView.h:68:65:
>   note: 'setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:' has been marked as being
>   introduced in iOS 11.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 8.0.0
>   @property(nonatomic) UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior
>   contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0),tvos(11.0));
>                                                                   ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:270:27:
>   note: enclose 'setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:' in an @available
>   check to silence this warning
>         _webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = _savedContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior;
>                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:308:5:
>   error: implicit declaration of function
>   'RCTUnsafeExecuteOnMainQueueSync' is invalid in C99
>   [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>       RCTUnsafeExecuteOnMainQueueSync(^{
>       ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:309:8:
>   error: implicit declaration of function 'RCTSharedApplication' is
>   invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>         [RCTSharedApplication() setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
>          ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:309:8:
>   error: bad receiver type 'int'
>         [RCTSharedApplication() setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:318:5:
>   error: implicit declaration of function
>   'RCTUnsafeExecuteOnMainQueueSync' is invalid in C99
>   [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>       RCTUnsafeExecuteOnMainQueueSync(^{
>       ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:319:8:
>   error: implicit declaration of function 'RCTSharedApplication' is
>   invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>         [RCTSharedApplication() setStatusBarHidden:self->_savedStatusBarHidden animated:YES];
>          ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:319:8:
>   error: bad receiver type 'int'
>         [RCTSharedApplication() setStatusBarHidden:self->_savedStatusBarHidden animated:YES];
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:320:8:
>   error: bad receiver type 'int'
>         [RCTSharedApplication() setStatusBarStyle:self->_savedStatusBarStyle animated:YES];
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:403:29:
>   warning: 'setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:' is only available on iOS
>   11.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
>           _webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = behavior;
>                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In module 'UIKit' imported from ../../react-native/React/Views/RCTView.h:12:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIScrollView.h:68:65:
>   note: 'setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:' has been marked as being
>   introduced in iOS 11.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 8.0.0
>   @property(nonatomic) UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior
>   contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0),tvos(11.0));
>                                                                   ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:403:29:
>   note: enclose 'setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:' in an @available
>   check to silence this warning
>           _webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = behavior;
>                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:684:5:
>   error: implicit declaration of function 'RCTJSONStringify' is invalid
>   in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>       RCTJSONStringify(eventInitDict, NULL)
>       ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:684:5:
>   warning: format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'int'
>   [-Wformat]
>       RCTJSONStringify(eventInitDict, NULL)
>       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:1003:61:
>   warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
>       if ([error.domain isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 102 || [error.domain
>   isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 101) {
>           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~
>   /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:1003:61:
>   note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this
>   warning
>       if ([error.domain isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 102 || [error.domain
>   isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 101) {
>                                                               ^
>           (                                                                       )
>   /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:1003:137:
>   warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
>       if ([error.domain isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 102 || [error.domain
>   isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 101) {
>                                                                                    ~~
>
> ```
> /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:1003:137:
> note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this
> warning
>     if ([error.domain isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 102 || [error.domain
> isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 101) {
>                                                                                                                                         ^
>                                                                                     (                                                                     
> )
> /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:1221:11:
> error: implicit declaration of function 'RCTJSONStringify' is invalid
> in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>           RCTJSONStringify(cookie.name, NULL),
>           ^ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:1221:11:
> warning: format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'int'
> [-Wformat]
>           RCTJSONStringify(cookie.name, NULL),
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:1222:11:
> warning: format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'int'
> [-Wformat]
>           RCTJSONStringify(cookie.value, NULL)];
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/user/projects/myapp/test-webview/ios-app/node_modules/react-native-webview/ios/RNCWebView.m:1224:54:
> warning: format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'int'
> [-Wformat]
>           [script appendFormat:@" + '; Path=' + %@", RCTJSONStringify(cookie.path, NULL)];
>                                                 ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                                                 %d 14 warnings and 12 errors generated.
> ```

How do we resolve this?

Environment:

- OS: Mac
- OS version: Catalina 10.15.3
- react-native version: 0.37
- react-native-webview version: 9.0.2

Comment: I think this RN Webview was added much later than your version. It must have been added around v.0.57 so if you don't intend on upgrading soon you probably should go with the WebView imported from react-native

Comment: @needsleep But they're deprecating the WebView component right? How can we proceed?

Comment: If you want to use the new Webview the only choice I see is upgrading your project, preferably to the latest version. They are deprecating the old Webview, but since you're in a previous version, you won't be affected by this. It will always work in your case. But you will have a problem when you decide to upgrade, you will need to do a small refactoring to your code and use the new Webview. But this won't be much work I think.